# Is this possible to set Attributes in an Class Extension?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, attributes, extension-methods

Is this possible to use `<Attributes>` on a method in a Class extension ?

Here is a Class A

```
Public Class Goblin
  Inherits Monster

  Enum goblinsRole
    Chief
    Grount
  End Enum

  Public Property name As String
  Public Property role As goblinsRole

  Private healthPoints As Integer

  Public Sub New(into As Integer)
     healthPoints = into
  End Sub

 Public Sub hitBy(damage As Integer)
    <...>
 End Sub

 <ValidationMethod()>
 Public Function checkByTheWitchDoctor()
    <...>
 End Function

 <ValidationMethod()>
 Public Function isAlive()
    <...>
 End Function
End Class
```

Here is an extension of this class A

```
Module ModuleExtension

 <ValidationMethod()>
 <Extension()>
  Public Sub PrintDateOfDeath(ByVal aGoblin As DomainModelFake.Goblin)
    <...>
  End Sub

 <Extension()>
 <ValidationMethod()>
  Public Function smashedByAGrount(ByVal aGoblin As DomainModelFake.Goblin) As Boolean
     <...>
  End Function

End Module
```

When I use reflection to get the methods that are tagged with this attribute, I only get the list of methods that are located in the Class A definition without those that are located in the extension.

In extenso, it means that I only see :

- checkByTheWitchDoctor()
- isAlive()

but i do **NOT** see :

- PrintDateOfDeath()
- smashedByAGrount()

**is this a normal behavior of reflection ? It doesn't search into the extensions ?**

Comment: Try yourself and come with code.

Comment: @Romil What makes you think I didn't try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you try to find all methods of the `Goblin` class, and if that is the case, then yes, this is the normal behavior of reflection.

Extension methods are **not** a member of the type they are designed for. If you do `Type.[GetType]("Goblin").GetMethods()`, you will only get the methods defined there.

Extension methods are nothing but static (Shared in VB) methods that are decorated with a special attribute. So if you want to find those, you need to get the methods of `ModuleExtension`.

If you do not know the name of `ModuleExtension` at runtime, you could try looking for all static types in the assembly, and search those for static methods marked with an `ExtensionAttribute` and accepting a first parameter of type `Goblin`.

Comment: If I don't know if a class has been extended or not, do you see any means to get the method names (within this extension) if they are correctly tagged? Because I will not know the name of this "ModeleExtension"...

Comment: @Rabskatran Edited my answer with a possible approach. Why don't you know the name of the Module? Usually extension methods are a compile-time concept.